# How do I get microsoftreportviewer on my Windows Forms form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pdf

I am trying to put a PSD file on my form using Microsoft report viewer, but I cannot find it. Where is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a "Reporting" tab in the toolbox, its in there.
If you do not have that tab, right-click in the toolbox, select "Choose Items", and select the ReportViewer box.

Comment: i dont have it. do u know if 2008 express has it? thats what i am using

Comment: It does not, but you can download it from microsoft at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=b67b9445-c206-4ff7-8716-a8129370fa1d